# Julia Forward Differentiation of vectors

Tags: julia, ode, differential-equations

I have this set of equations (the Hamilton ray equations) which is the partial derivative of vector x with respect to t equal to the negative derivative of some function D and vise versa.
An example function D is shown below

```
function D(x::AbstractVector,k::AbstractVector)
    -k.*k - x
end
```

In julia I implemented this the gradients of D as:

∂D∂k(x,k) = ForwardDiff.gradient(D(x,k),k)

∂D∂x(x,k) = ForwardDiff.gradient(D(x,k),x)

but when I call ∂D∂x(x,k) with some vectors x and k, I get

```
MethodError: objects of type Vector{Float64} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

Is it only possible to implement piece-wise (i.e not vectorially) or am I missing some syntax?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

I was expecting a vector output, not an error

Comment: You might want `ForwardDiff.jacobian(k -> D(x,k), k)`. First, passing just `D(x,k)` as an argument can't work, as this is evaluated to a vector before being passed to the function, and the ForwardDiff functions all expect a function as their first argument, like `k -> D(x,k)`. (Some languages hold things unevaluated, but Julia does not.) And second, `ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x)` expects that `f(x)` is just a number, not a vector. `ForwardDiff.gradient(k -> sum(D(x,k)), k)` would make a number first.

Comment: The error produced is referring to your call of `gradiant(x::Function,y::Vector{Float64})` . You are passing the output of `D(x,k)` as the first argument. Since `D(x,k)` returns a vector, the function tries to call a vector as if it were a function, leading to an error. The function that you may be looking to use as a param is `x->D(x,k)`